# Dozer initialize property with empty string

Tags: mapping, dozer

I need to initialize with Dozer a String property on destination obect with empty string.

Imagine these objects:

```
SRC
public class Container {
            private String animalName;  
....
DEST
public class Animal {
    private String name;
    private String type;
```

I need to initialize from Container to Animal and to set **type** property to "" and not null:

The only way I found is to write a Custom Converter as follows:

```
public class InitializeStringConverter extends DozerConverter<Container, String>{

    public InitializeStringConverter() {
        super(Container.class, String.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Container convertFrom(String arg0, Container arg1) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String convertTo(Container arg0, String arg1) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

and having this mapping:

```
<mapping>
        <class-a>it.alten.sample.mapping.Container</class-a>
        <class-b>it.alten.sample.mapping.Animal</class-b>
        <field custom-converter="it.alten.sample.mapping.converter.InitializeStringConverter">
            <a>this</a>
            <b>type</b>
        </field>
        <!-- 
        <field>
            <a>animalName</a>
            <b>name</b>
        </field>
         -->
        <field>
            <a>animalType</a>
            <b>type</b>
        </field>
    </mapping>
```

Is there a more concise way to accomplish this task?

Kind regards
Massimo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dozer copies and converts values, it should not init fields in custom way as I think.

My solution for your problem:

1. Enable null mapping for class or field - [docs](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/advancedConfiguration.html)
2. Create setter, which init field with empty value instead of null, like:

   `void setType(String type) {this.type = (type != null ? type : "");}`

I think, it more clear solution for your problem, because null control is functionality of setter and it's right.